# lstlisting - macro only for specific language

Tags: code, lstlisting

I am currently using following code for G-code formatting. Unfortunately I have no idea how do I enable the macro just for the new "gcode" language.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{light-gray2}{gray}{0.90}

\lstdefinelanguage{gcode}{
    morekeywords={G1, G21, G28, G92, G90, M82, M107, M109, M104}, columns=fullflexible, basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},frame=tb,framesep=8pt,framerule=0.4pt, belowskip=0em
}   

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
\lst@ProcessOther {"45}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{E}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{E}}}% used with other fonts
\lst@ProcessOther {"53}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{S}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{S}}}% used with other fonts  
\lst@ProcessOther {"54}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{T}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{T}}}% used with other fonts  
\lst@ProcessOther {"46}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{F}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{F}}}% used with other fonts                
\lst@ProcessOther {"58}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{X}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{X}}}% used with other fonts         
\lst@ProcessOther {"59}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{Y}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{Y}}}% used with other fonts
\lst@ProcessOther {"5A}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{Z}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{Z}}}% used with other fonts         
\@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother
```

This macro + gcode language works as follows. Problem is the CCPutMacro works for all languages. For example language=java and i want it to only work when langiage = gcode.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language = gcode, numbers = none, escapechar = !] 
 G1 X0.00000 Y0.00000 E0.00000
 G1 X2.00000 Y4.00000 E0.02000
 G1 X4.00000 Y4.00000 E0.02500
 G1 X2.00000 Y0.00000 E0.04500
 G1 X4.00000 Y0.00000 E0.05000
 G1 X6.00000 Y4.00000 E0.07000
 G1 X8.00000 Y4.00000 E0.07500
 G1 X6.00000 Y0.00000 E0.09500
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, what is "gcode" and "new gcode"? Please explain better ...

Comment: You should extend your sample to a complete but minimal, compilable document that shows the result you get and where it differs from what you want.

Comment: I added example code + package and colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new environment for `gcode` and execute the `\lst@CCPutMacro` part only there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{light-gray2}{gray}{0.90}

\lstdefinelanguage{gcode}{
    morekeywords={G1, G21, G28, G92, G90, M82, M107, M109, M104},
    columns=fullflexible,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
    frame=tb,
    framesep=8pt,
    framerule=0.4pt,
    belowskip=0em,
}

\makeatletter
\def\gcodeletters{%
  \lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"45}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{E}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{E}}}% used with other fonts
  \lst@ProcessOther {"53}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{S}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{S}}}% used with other fonts  
  \lst@ProcessOther {"54}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{T}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{T}}}% used with other fonts  
  \lst@ProcessOther {"46}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{F}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{F}}}% used with other fonts                
  \lst@ProcessOther {"58}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{X}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{X}}}% used with other fonts         
  \lst@ProcessOther {"59}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{Y}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{Y}}}% used with other fonts
  \lst@ProcessOther {"5A}{%
    \lst@ttfamily
    {\textbf{Z}}% used with ttfamily
    {\textbf{Z}}}% used with other fonts         
  \@empty\z@\@empty
}
\makeatother
\lstnewenvironment{gcode}[1][]{\gcodeletters\lstset{language=gcode,#1}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{gcode}[numbers = none, escapechar = !] 
 G1 X0.00000 Y0.00000 E0.00000
 G1 X2.00000 Y4.00000 E0.02000
 G1 X4.00000 Y4.00000 E0.02500
 G1 X2.00000 Y0.00000 E0.04500
 G1 X4.00000 Y0.00000 E0.05000
 G1 X6.00000 Y4.00000 E0.07000
 G1 X8.00000 Y4.00000 E0.07500
 G1 X6.00000 Y0.00000 E0.09500
\end{gcode}

\begin{lstlisting}{language=Java}
XYE
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I finally got it how environments work in LaTeX. Much appreciated answer.

Comment: @JanVorisek You're welcome. By the way, are you related to Jan Václav Voříšek (1791-1825)?

Comment: I am not as far as I know. It's nice to  hear someone knows about czech composers and musicians though :-)